# div border bottom is overlapped with something

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I a `div` that is full of content and I gave it `box-shadow`. Everything was ok till I make that `div` slider using `slick slider`. Now my problem is that after using slik slider, the bottom shadow of div is not displaying and I guess it's overlapped with something. I applied many changes but no benefit! How can I fix that? Following is my minimal of code:

HTML:

```
<div id="recent-posts" class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 ">
            <div class="posts">
                <div class="posts-div">
                    <div class="img-hover">
                        <img src="images/post1.jpg" class="img-responsive">

                        </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
            <div class="posts">
                <div class="posts-div">
                    <div class="img-hover">
                        <img src="images/post2.jpg" class="img-responsive">

                        </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
            <div class="posts">
                <div class="posts-div">
                    <div class="img-hover">
                        <img src="images/post3.jpg" class="img-responsive">

                        </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
            <div class="posts">
                <div class="posts-div">
                    <div class="img-hover">
                        <img src="images/post4.jpg" class="img-responsive">

                        </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#recent-posts{
    /*height: 350px;*/
    /*display: flex;*/
    /*justify-content: center;*/
    position: relative;
    /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.posts{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 375px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #888888;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.posts img{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-height: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

Script:

```
$('#recent-posts').slick({
        dots: false,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        responsive:[
            {
                breakpoint: 770,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    dots: false
                }
            }]
    });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j8upvh3c/1/)

Comment: That's because your div has margin-top, margin-left and margin-right set to 20px but no similar margin-bottom rule.

Comment: @Pyromonk Oh, You're Right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `margin-bottom` to your `.posts` element to gain some bottom margin which overflows from parent `div`.

```
.posts{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 375px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #888888;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom:20px; //this here
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/j8upvh3c/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j8upvh3c/4/

Setting margin 20px from all side should fix the issue. You were applying for top, right, left but not bottom.

```
.posts{
    margin: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 375px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #888888;
}
```